# How to stop a c++ process in python, when python invoke that c++ process using "Python.h"

Tags: python, c++

In a c++ program, I used "Python.h" to implement a c++ function which can be used in python. 
In python, I want this c++ function to run in a limited time.
So, I used a function decorator in python to let the c++ function run in a limited time. If the function exceed the given time, it will raise a RuntimeError, then I just let the function return.
But I the result seems not good, after the c++ function being called many times, the program runs slower and slower, and finally crash.

This is the decorator:

```
def set_timeout(num, callback):

    def wrap(func):

        def handle(signum, frame):  

            raise RuntimeError()

        def to_do(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handle) 
                signal.alarm(num)  
                print('start alarm signal.')
                r = func(*args, **kwargs)
                print('close alarm signal.')
                signal.alarm(0)  
                return r
            except RuntimeError as e:
                callback()

        return to_do

    return wrap

def after_timeout():

    return
```

This is the python invoked c++ function with decorator:

```
@set_timeout(3,after_timeout)
def pytowr_run(gait,tgt,time_interval,tm,posture=None,init_dic={}):
    pos,cost,varDict = pytowr.run(gait,tgt[0],tgt[1],time_interval,tm,posture,init_dic)
    return pos
```

Is there any way to let the python invoked c++ function stop running in python?

Comment: If you want to stop a process, it doesn't matter which programming language the program running in that process was created from. There is no such thing as a "C++ process" in that sense. As new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

To stop the c++ function you'll need to send it a signal. But just sending a signal is not enough. In the c++ function you will probably need to set some interrupt points to check if a signal was sent. Example:

```
#include <csignal>
#include <atomic>

constexpr int SIGALRM = 14;
std::atomic_bool signal_received;

void signal_handler(int signal) {
    // check 'signal' if necessary
    signal_received.store(true);
}

void config() { //call it at some start point...
    signal_received.store(false);
    std::signal(SIGALRM, signal_handler);
}

void your_function(/*args*/) {
    /* do some work */
    if (signal_received.load()) return; //interrupt point. Exiting your c++ function...
    // the interrupt point must be placed in a strategic place
    /* maybe more work */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a better solution  if i'm understanding your goal,  is invoke a C/C++ function and pass in the allotted time into the C/C++ function instead of trying kill the function from python which is doable but makes the code harder to read and debug.

```
#include datetime.h 
PyDateTime_IMPORT

bool your_function(passed_in_vars, start_time * PyDateTime_DateTime allotted_time* int ) 
{

    kill_time = PyDateTime_DATE_GET_MICROSECOND(PyDateTime_DateTime *o) + allotted 
    /* do some work */
    if ( allotted_time > kill_time  ) 
        return; //interrupt point. Exiting your c++ function...

    //do more work... 
}
```

This makes the code easier no loops or wait states on the python side and makes its easier on the C++ side to know when to kill the function and fire off any clean up code.

And finding Bottles necks easier on the  C++  side..